# Please guide me how to make my question clear?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, closed-questions, editing-help

One of my questions was closed yesterday. After that I've edited it multiple times. But it seems it is still not completely clear. Following is the question:

> [Do fixed and absolutely positioned elements not take the full width of their container like block elements? If yes then why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35308992/3429430)

I guess that what was not clear was that what I meant by `block-level` elements. I've clarified that in the question. The confusion arose in my mind after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15763187/3429430). I am still not sure whether absolutely/fixed positioned elements are block-level elements or not. I am new to programming. There are many things in w3c draft which are above my level. I am also not fluent in English so sometimes I find it difficult to understand MDN reference; that is why I ask questions on stackoverflow. E.g. I still don't understood somewhat the answer given by user Chris; because I don't know why he mentioned **non replaced** elements. Would the rendering be different if there were a replaced element?

Please tell me what is not clear in the question; I'll edit it further.

Thank you.

Comment: The answer is quite explicit and quotes all the necessary information and sources you *and other users* might need (although these could have been found with a Google search). The fact that you cannot quite understand it is unfortunate but, IMO, not a reason to re-open the question.

Comment: @Paulie_D That is why I am asking what to improve. I'll understand the answer once I revise the basics again. I do not say reopen it becasue I can't comprehend the answers. I am saying tell me what is not clear; I'll improve the question.

Comment: If you understood the answer you wouldn't need to edit the question. It's kind of circular that way. Perhaps ping @Boltclock to see if he's willing?

Comment: Actually I understood why it works as inline-block; because setting the position absolute takes the box out of it's container so there is nothing to fit in. The box adjusted it's width to acompane the containing text. There is small doubt about non-replaced elements and w3c's paragraph only.

Comment: Then that's probably a **different** question.

Comment: I have to edit it. If it remained closed no one can provide more answers to it.

Comment: Yeah that's a different question. But that's why I said I have some confusion remaining.

Comment: @Gimby  Who wrote the w3c draft can answer it because he/she would know exactly _why_ it is defined this way and what is its specific purpose.

Comment: @Gimby I think that is not going to happen. But what can happen is, that somewhere in the w3c draft the authors might have mentioned _why_ it is like that and _what_ is its exact purpose. I also think that asking _why_ in a question isn't  bad and doesn't make my question _unclear_ in any way.

Comment: @Gimby First off, it is not _locked_; it is _closed_. My bad, I wrote the title incorrect. I appreciate your suggestion. But I personally don't feel that _why_ makes my question unclear. No doubt _why_ makes it difficult to answer but I still don't think asking _why_ is bad. If it was then [these 1828413 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=why) should also be bad.

Comment: For starters, don't add "thank you", "please" and other demonstrations of "politeness". We don't care about those.

Comment: @Braiam It's fine if you don't care 'bout that. It's just that I don't like censorship.

Comment: It is not about censorship but how we feel questions are in their best shape. I feel that is one of the criteria for me to re-open edited questions. You can have it your away but I'm not going to spend my re-open vote on that for now, sorry.

Comment: @user31782: It's about getting to the point without boring your readers to tears, and respecting the local norms. No need to antagonize any viewers right from the start...

Comment: @user31782 I thought your question was crystal clear. Not sure why others thought it wasn't.

Comment: @rene, Briaiam, Deduplicator. I am not a starter here. As per the current network wide stake exchange policy you cannot enforce the "No-thank-you" policy( or etiquette or whatever it is called). Till my account isn't suspended I'll not accept this norm.

Comment: Well, then you are going to have a hell of fun here.

Comment: I agree that excessive politeness is annoying. But a single "thanks" at the end of the post is hardly going to "*bore anyone to tears*" nor is it "antagonizing". Showing gratitude and a bit of decency never hurt anyone. The fact that this was pointed out in this particular post is almost hilarious. Not everyone was raised in a caravan you know :)

Comment: OK, I can accept that you don't accept my norms but do you still expect me to help you out with your issue?

Comment: @rene, you don't answer questions that say "thanks" at the end? :)

Comment: @rene Well, the _please_ had only one purpose that I am requesting to everyone. People here volunteer their time for nothing. Can I _order_ you guys, hey yo help me? The question is a polite request and the _please_ is what distinguish a request from an order.

Comment: I do edit them vigorously @Chris

Comment: @rene you forgot this one.

Comment: I stop wasting my time if OP's decide to roll-back my edits @Chris

Comment: Talk about finding a button and sewing a vest onto it :D

Comment: @Chris see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/165773)

Comment: @gnat, See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) the most upvoted comment in OP question (94 upvotes from JonH), as well as the comments in the first answer (146 from mike4ty4 and 143 from DavidLozzi), as well as several others.

Comment: @Chris compare these numbers 94 and 146 - and add that those who'd want can not vote comments down - compare them to score 708 (+732/-24) of the top answer

Comment: @Chris: So what? There's always a very noisy group which won't adapt to local norms, whatever the reason for those, and those comments aren't censored. Consensus is still clear.

Comment: Yet those 240 didn't vote the post down (only 24 did). So your argument is flawed already. And you're comparing votes on the main topic against votes on comments (the OP question tends to get most attention). You're also only including 2 comments out of several (the 3rd one I mentioned for example). Another way to look at it is that they were the most upvoted *comments* in the entire topic. So concensus isn't as clear as you might think. At the very least there is no "norm" here. Just the norm you *want*.

Comment: Though I can agree that things like "hello everyone", "please help me with this assignment" or anything else that might be seen as extensive can, and should be, omitted. A **single** "thanks" doesn't make *any* difference whatsoever, and any argument against this is as absurd as the argument of requiring people to write `it's` instead of `it is` because it's 2 characters longer and is, as such, *boring readers to tears* and *disrespecting local norms*.

Comment: @Chris: Of course the dissenting comments are the most upvoted ones, as nobody saw the need to thoroughly rebut them in the comments, as that would be redundant with the post. Also, people already upvoted the post... And if you want to go by vote-count, than just take the most-voted *answer*, or maybe even the most voted *comment*. Taking more than one would be double-counting... Regarding "there's a dissenting voice, and thus there's no clear consensus": If you go that route, but still want consensus, you need to censor every dissenter, thoroughly suppress them, or just get rid of them.

Comment: A single thanks doesn't make much difference, if you look at a single post, or even just a handful, true. But it adds up, and for a knowledgebase, it's unprofessional to boot. Actually, flagrantly breaking local convention is rude at best wherever you go, even if you don't understand the reasons for them, and just because you are set in your ways and there are some others that are as well doesn't change anything.

Comment: Searching for "thanks", "appreciated", and similar words adds up to roughly 3-4 million questions of the sites 11 million, so a good 1/3 out of *all* questions ever posted. As per the post, you can see that there are many that have different opinions. Even there it seems to be roughly a 1:3 ratio at best. That's hardly a "convention", rather different opinions -- most of which just seem to be opposed to the *excessive* use of moot content, which I am opposed to as well and (as per your above comment) so do you.

Comment: @Deduplicator I follow *global* convention and SO being on the web, a **single** thanks is perfectly fine in my book. Don't make it sound like 99% of folks here never thank people and thus portraying showing appreciation as some kind of sin or social opprobrium.

Comment: If I [search for "thanks" on the main site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=thanks), I only get a good 2 million results (there are about 30 million posts now). And on the first fifteen posts found, only in one case wasn't it somehow the subject of the post. Ok, now let's [narrow it down to questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=thanks+is%3Aq), we are still at 1.9 million of 11 million asked, and a single case in the first fifteen results where it wasn't content.  Anyway, global convention (of which "on the internet" is a part) is to be polite by learning & following local convention.

Comment: You expected to find "thanks" in an answer? 1.9/11 is still 17%. Add to that other synonyms such as "appreciated" and other "banned words" such as "please" and the like and you'll get the figures I said earlier. Again, there isn't a site-wide "convention" if 40% of users don't follow it. Anyway, you somehow failed to follow the "local convention" yourself numerous times, because according to history you have 30-40 posts with the words "thanks", "thank you", "please", etc. Some even had "please" in the title! Your whole stance and argument is just completely moot at this point.

Comment: Please everyone stop. This is way too off topic. I got that the community sees post containing "Thank you" and "Please" as low quality and tend to downvote and close them. I'll improve and clear other things in the question. I don't care about the mundane reputation, I don't care about the mundane score. I wanted to know how it works and chris has explained it well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35308992/timeline) I can see why your question was closed as unclear. I wouldn't have close voted if I knew my close vote was binding but [Boltclock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) decided differently.

I'm not versed into the particular issue you have trouble with but I've read into the topic again and I find it hard to match the issue you describe in the text and the code you provide. If anything needs to be changed either a more detailed example or maybe a screenshot can help in that case.

In your paragraph where you ask the question you ask for why things are designed as they are. I personally think that question is on the brink of opinion based if not too broad. So that would put your question on the other end of unclear.

You also ask for links to reference documentation. Users that will try to answer will be helped if you link to docs you already read or saw. This will prevent answers to provide links to docs you already read but didn't help or it will clarify where your line of reasoning is off because you interpret the doc wrong or didn't find the correct one.

With these small changes I think your question should be able to gather enough re-open votes.

Let me end with a personal observation. I have tried to edit your question to remove noise and also to give it another push so it got some renewed attention. In the comments here and on the SO question I see you choose certain wording that makes me wonder why I should help you out at all. I'm trying to be respectful and helpful. I don't understand why that only seems to apply to me.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've reworded the code and added an explanation to it. You are right; it required some explanation. I've not read the w3c draft fully and don't know which section would be useful to my question; that's why I asked for the reference(s). Actually apart for w3school website I haven't read anything else related to html/css contemplatively.

Comment: By rolling back your edit I didn't mean to be disrespectful either. To me not saying thank you to someone who helps is _rude_. I know most of the guys here don't like "Hi, hello, thank you stuff". But I am me. I am human. I can't suppress my emotions.

Comment: I've elaborated on the _why_ portion too. It's impossible to completely avoid opinions for the _why_ portion. But this is an important concern for me. Without _why_ the question is purpose less because I know the absolutely/fixed positioned boxes are _defined_ this way; that's why they render this way.

Comment: @user31782 I have removed again the *Thank in you advance* and I've cast the last re-open vote. Good luck with your question.